# Adobe InDesign hangs indefinitely when I try to duplicate pages using ExtendScript

Tags: extendscript, adobe-indesign

I have a very simple ExtendScript script which creates a new document out of a subset of the current active document:

```
var sourceDocument = app.activeDocument;
var i, j;

for(i = 0; i < sourceDocument.layers.length; i++) {
  sourceDocument.layers.item(i).locked = false;
}
for(i = 0; i < sourceDocument.spreads.length; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < sourceDocument.spreads.item(i).textFrames.length; j++) {
    if(sourceDocument.spreads.item(i).textFrames.item(j).locked) {
      sourceDocument.spreads.item(i).textFrames.item(j).locked = false;
    }
  }
}

var destDocument = app.documents.add();
var firstPageIndex = 0; // In the actual script, this is chosen by the user.
var lastPageIndex = 5; // In the actual script, this is chosen by the user.

destDocument.importStyles(ImportFormat.paragraphStylesFormat, new File(sourceDocument.filePath + "/" + sourceDocument.name), GlobalClashResolutionStrategy.LOAD_ALL_WITH_OVERWRITE);
destDocument.importStyles(ImportFormat.characterStylesFormat, new File(sourceDocument.filePath + "/" + sourceDocument.name), GlobalClashResolutionStrategy.LOAD_ALL_WITH_OVERWRITE);
destDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = sourceDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits;
destDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = sourceDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits;
destDocument.documentPreferences.facingPages = sourceDocument.documentPreferences.facingPages;
destDocument.documentPreferences.pageHeight = sourceDocument.documentPreferences.pageHeight;
destDocument.documentPreferences.pageWidth = sourceDocument.documentPreferences.pageWidth;
destDocument.documentPreferences.pageSize = sourceDocument.documentPreferences.pageSize;
destDocument.documentPreferences.allowPageShuffle = true;

var range = sourceDocument.pages.itemByRange(firstPageIndex, lastPageIndex);
range.duplicate(LocationOptions.AFTER, destDocument.pages[destDocument.pages.length - 1]);
destDocument.pages[0].remove(); // An empty spread containing an empty page is added when the new document is created and we cannot remove it before other pages are inserted (Documents must have at least one page)
```

This script works perfectly on many documents. But when I execute it against one particular document (let's call it foo.indd), InDesign becomes unresponsive when executing the duplication: `range.duplicate(LocationOptions.AFTER, destDocument.pages[destDocument.pages.length - 1]);`. From then on, the only thing I can do is force InDesign to quit.

Is this an InDesign bug? How can I find which part of this particular document is creating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really say what's wrong in your example but if indesign hangs, that might caused by the loops ( to infinity and beyond :) )

So you may try to avoid issues by outputting the loop limit to avoid InDesign re-calculation

```
var limit = …
for ( i = 0; i<limit ; i++)…
```

Additionally you could try to write info on the console to get info where InDesign is actually being stuck. So write informations on the fly on a report file and you might finally identify the issue area.

Also, you can try to interrogate every key items to see if the file has some issue.

Last but not least, try a manual export to idml of this file, re open and run again the script. Sometimes files become clunky and passing by idml fix most of them.

Comment: The problem occurs when using the `duplicate` function; it's not the loops. Going through IDML is a good idea, I'll try. I don't understand what you mean by "interrogate every key items to see if the file has some issues". Could you explain that idea a little more?

Comment: Exporting to IDML and re-importing does not solve the problem.

Comment: I am happy it fixed the issue. By key items, I was meaning to get back info on specific parts of the code where issues could rise.

Comment: Actually, it didn't fix the issue. I still haven't found why the problem occurs, yet I have inspected the document through and through by looking at all its properties and comparing them with another (working) document.

Comment: Hi my bad, I read too quick :D I will have a second look at it.

Comment: Hi. I have the some problem. 
It happens to me when the interval of pages to duplicate is greather than 150 aprox. For example, if I try `app.activeDocument.pages.itemByRange(0,50).duplicate( ....;` work fine but `app.activeDocument.pages.itemByRange(0,200).duplicate( ....;` don't work. I work, the sentence never finish. ¿¿??

Answer (score 0):

Give this script a try onto your probleamtic file. If it fails, please have a look at the report it should have generated onto the desktop.

http://www.loicaigon.com/downloads/cloneDocument.jsx

Loic
http://www.loicaigon.com

Comment: I get a "Reference error: Invalid object" and this in report.txt: Starting main()
calling cloneDocument()
entering cloneDocument()
Unlocking all layers
Unlocking all textFrames
adding destDocument
importing Paragraph Styles
importing Character Styles
applying horizontalMeasurementUnits
applying verticalMeasurementUnits
applying facingPages
applying pageHeight
applying pageWidth
applying pageSize
applying allowPageShuffle
Getting pages by range
Duplicating pages